# How to record mp4 with camera

Tags: 14.04, video

I haven't seen a question that has an answer to this. I have a camera, I can record video files with cheese. The problem is that the video files are `ẁebm` ... I need `mp4` videos. How can I record mp4 videos in Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not use a converter? http://www.zamzar.com/convert/webm-to-mp4/

Comment: @Zacharee1 Sometimes they corrupt the video.

Comment: If you wanna go semi-pro just for your personal vids you can use Handbrake. It's in the repositories.

Comment: Perhaps vlc: http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2010/07/13/webcam-recording-using-vlc-on-linux/